# Update multilingual content with AJAX in Yii

Tags: ajax, yii

Refer to my code below, when user click on `en` button, the content will be changed to English, while clicking `tw` button, the content will be changed to Chinese.

However, the page will be refreshed each time when user click either `en` or `tw` button. I want to ask how can I implement AJAX content update in this case?

The result is when user click either `en` or `tw` button, the page won't be refreshed to change the content language.

Thanks

I have refer to Yii docs [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/49/update-content-in-ajax-with-partialrender/), but seem that it is not appropriate for my case

`C:\wamp\www\website\protected\views\site\index.php`

```
<?php
$lang = isset($_GET["lang"]) ? $_GET["lang"] : "en_uk";
$lang = $lang == "en" ? "en_uk" : "zh_tw";

Yii::app()->setLanguage($lang);
?>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="get">
    <input type="submit" value="en" name="lang" />
    <input type="submit" value="tw" name="lang" />
</form>

<div class="main">
    <?php echo Yii::t(Yii::app()->controller->id, "Causeway Bay"); ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best practice is to reload the page in these cases, because usually you have to update so much, that it is just not worth it.

That said, CHtml's [ajaxSubmitButton](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml/#ajaxSubmitButton-detail) is the cleanest way to implement this, because you can map every event of your call very easily. It looks something like this:

```
<?php 
echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton('en', CHtml::normalizeUrl(array('site/changeLanguage')),
array(
    'error'=>'js:function(){
        alert("error");
    }',
    //if you add a return false in this, it will not submit. 
    'beforeSend'=>'js:function(){
        alert("beforeSend");                                            
    }',
    'success'=>'js:function(data){
        alert("success, data from server: "+data);
    }',
    'complete'=>'js:function(){
        alert("complete");
    }',
    //'update'=>'#where_to_put_the_response',
)
);
?>
```

You don't have to use every parameter of course. The update parameter can update a HTML tag instantly.

EDIT:
This can be done easily if you use the controller's [renderPartial](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#renderPartial-detail) method, for instance  in your site controller if you have the action responsible for the index.

```
public function actionIndex(){
   //get variables, etc


   if(Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest) {
      $lang = $_POST['nameOfSubmit'];

   }else {
      //...
   }
   //if the 3rd parameter is true, the method returns the generated HTML to a variable
   $page = $this->renderPartial('_page', array(/*parameters*/ ), true); 
   echo $page; 
}
```

And then, in your view file you can simply have

```
<?php echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton('en', CHtml::normalizeUrl(array('site/index')),
array('update'=>'#content_div',));?>
```

and

```
<?php echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton('tw', CHtml::normalizeUrl(array('site/index')),
    array('update'=>'#content_div',));?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so your suggestion is to update/replace the related HTML tag by ajax?

Comment: If you write an action that renders partially the page (or a large part of the page), then yes, it can be done fairly easily with ajax. I'll update my response with an example.

Comment: +1 for the code example. Also, could you please explain the use of CHtml::normalizeUrl? Thanks

Comment: CHtml::normalizeUrl is useful if you have multiple parameters, otherwise you can use the CController's createUrl ($this->createUrl in views).